# CSS - Aligning the child of a flex container to center of screen not working properly

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm making a small Etch-a-Sketch-esque webpage.

For now, I'm just trying to get the CSS of the page right before moving onto the Javascript that will generate a canvas of a designated size, so I'm working with a 16x16 grid of divs statically on the webpage.

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sensanaty/pen/GexqdW) for what I have so far. Sorry about the ridiculously long HTML, as I said for now I'm just working on the formatting and put in a 16x16 grid (`800px by 800px`) of divs with class `.tabletCanvas`. Basically, just 256 divs that have that class.

As you can see, the "canvas" is sticking to the left-hand side, and I want it to look like it does [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWb70.jpg) (very rough outline done in 5 minutes using photoshop).

What I've tried so far:

- Many different values for `flex:`. What happens is that, without setting a `max-width` or `max-height` (from my understanding of flexbox, specifying specific heights and widths defeats the purpose of using it and that everything should be handled through the `flex:` property), the grid will simply overflow to the right and fill up the rest of the screen. Obviously not ideal, as I want it contained within the 800x800 pixels, and even after specifying the `max-width` and `height`, it will still hang to the left.
- Making the `tabletContainer` a flex parent (container) itself, and trying all possible variations of `align-content`, `align-items` and `justify-content` within it. None of them had a visible effect
- Many different values of `align-self`, `justify-self` on the `.tabletCanvas` class.
- One thing that sprung to mind would be absolutely positioning the canvas div, but this defeats the purpose of using a flex container in the first place, I imagine

Something that I think might work would be to use the `align-content` or `align-items` properties on the `#bodyWrapper` to get all of its children to be centered, however if I do this then I risk ruining the flow of every other property and putting myself more or less back to square one where I started.

Another thing that sprung to mind was just to add a lot of `padding-left` to the `#sketchButtons`, however this also seems like a hilariously wrong and hacky approach to take.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make 2 columns: left (for buttons) and center (for grid). Give the center one a right margin equal to the width of the left column. Now all you need to do is center your grid into the center column and the internet is full of examples. There are other ways to do it (to ignore the left column altogether, but they're not as easy to control & implement. The above also allows you to easily control responsiveness (under some width make the left column full width and cancel center columns right margin.

Comment: make `#tabletContainer {margin: 0 auto;}` it will center div.

Comment: A [mcve] should be provided **within** the question, not as an external link alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to: 
set .tabletContainers position to absolute, 
set margin to auto, 
set left and right to 0,
and then set your top property as desired.

```
 .tabletContainer {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 111px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add absolute position to main content element, why did you decide to do this instead of the same approach on the menu sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

I made a [jsfiddle draft](https://jsfiddle.net/wyLsndzp/) of your case with a simplified styling. I hope you can analyse the code and spot the approach.

In a nutshell it's just a centered flex column and absolutely positioned menu.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}


.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  position: relative;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <div class="content">
    <nav class="menu">
      <button>Menu item</button>
      <button>Menu item</button>
      <button>Menu item</button>
    </nav>
    <div class="grid">Grid</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to center your grid horizontaly, here is a simple solution :

```
#tabletContainer {
  margin: auto; /* Center the tableContainer horizontaly */
}
#header {
  padding-left: 190px; /* The width of your sidebar, to align it with the tableContainer */
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222219;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header h1 {
  color: #F9C80E;
}

#bodyWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
  flex: 1 100%;
  align-self: baseline;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 190px; /* The width of the sidebar */
}

#sketchButtons {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.appButtons {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #424729;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.appButtons:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #424729;
}

.appButtons:active {
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

#tabletContainer {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  max-width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center it */
}

.tabletCanvas {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyWrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Etch-A-Sketch!</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="sketchButtons">
            <button class="appButtons" id="rainbowButton">Random Colors</button>
            <button class="appButtons" id="clearButton">Reset the Grid</button>
            <button class="appButtons" id="blackButton">Default Colors</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Drawing board gets targeted here -->
        <div id="tabletContainer">
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
            <div class="tabletCanvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```